# My customizer's setting doesn't set to the default and needed to click the control's "Default" button before it'll be set

Tags: php, functions, theme-development, customization, images

Here's my sample customizer's setting and control:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'themename_img', array(
    'type'           => 'theme_mod',
    'default'        => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/' . rawurlencode( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ) . '.gif',
    'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
    'transport'      => 'refresh'
));
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'img', array(
    'label'      => __( 'Image', 'theme-slug' ),
    'section'    => 'section_id',
    'settings'   => 'themename_img',
)));
```

The image at `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theme-name/images/' . rawurlencode( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ) . '.gif'` is already existing.. But why the control and the setting doesn't set to the default's value and needed to click the *"Default"* button before it'll be set to the default?

But when I change the `'themename_img'`s default from `'default' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/' . rawurlencode( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ) . '.gif'` to `'default' => 'image.gif'` the setting's default will be automatically set to the default even though the path location isn't valid. How can my customizer's setting and control be initially set to such `get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/' . rawurlencode( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ) . '.gif'` address? Is there an alternative?

#### Updates:

Upon debugging, the `rawurlencode( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) )` code is the suspect that's why I included it in my sample!

Comment: **Update #2:** The `rawurlencode()` function is the main suspect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what I've commented, the `rawurlencode()` function is the reason because WordPress have a lot of restrictions. I found that, that kind of problem will exist if you have a `%` percent sign *(in my case, produced by the `rawurlencode()`)* in your `'default' => $value`.

One of the solutions, encode some or the whole part of your path with `base64_encode()`:

```
$encode = get_template_directory_uri().'/images/'.get_bloginfo('name').'.gif';
...
    'default' => $encode,
...
```

And later decode it with `base64_decode()` before you use it:

```
$decode = base64_decode(get_theme_mod('themename_img'));
```